# How to draw a Flash object into a memory DC?

Tags: c++, vb.net, flash, gdi

I'm writing a small game (with DC), I would like to use some Flash files to show the animation to screen in my game, but i'm using memory DC to draw.

I would like change the FlashPlayer's output device to my memory DC. Is that possible? What should i do? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement an ActiveX container that uses IOleInPlaceSiteWindowless.  IOleInPlaceSiteWindowless contains a GetDC() function in which flash will draw to.

Here is a good example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33516/ATL-Windowless-ActiveX-Media-Container